# React: How to enable Button based on "If" statement

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, button

I have a button on my forum page which I want disabled unless you're logged in as an admin as defined in MongoDB. (In Mongo, I have a role document which shows as "admin" for particular users)

Will provide some code down below:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      questions: [], // used to store questions from API call
      answers: [], // used to store all answers stored in database
      filteredAnswers: [], // used to store the filtered answers for a given question
      displayAnswers: false, // used to display the answer modal or not
      disabled: true,
      role: null,
    };
  }

handleClickPostAnswer(questionID, questionText) {
    const answerInput = window.prompt(`Please enter your answer to Question ${questionID}: ${questionText}`, 'Enter answer here');
    if (answerInput === null) {
      console.log('No answer posted');
      return;
    }

    else if (this.state.role == 'admin') {
      console.log('User is an Admin');
      this.setState({
        disabled: false,
      })
    }
    
    // ADD ACTUAL USERNAME HERE
    this.postAnswer(questionID, answerInput, 'John');
    console.log(`Posted answer: ${answerInput}`);
  }

componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('/getquestions')
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data);
          this.setState({questions: response.data});
        });
  }

<tbody>
            {/* within the table, take array  */}
            {this.state.questions.map((question) => {
              return (
                <tr key = {question._id}>
                  <td>{question._id}</td>
                  <td>{question.questionText}</td>
                  <td>{question.username}</td>
                  <td>{question.labels}</td>
                  <td><Button disabled={this.state.disabled} onClick={() => this.handleClickPostAnswer(question._id, question.questionText)}>Answer</Button></td>
                  <td><Button onClick={() => this.handleClickReadAnswers(question._id)}>Display</Button></td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
```

Currently, the button seems to be disabled all the time even though I am logged in as a user that has the "admin" field attached to them in Mongo. Probably missing something simple but not sure why this will not work.

[How it looks in MongoDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3aJG.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could check the role and disable it accordingly.

```
<Button 
   disabled={this.state.role !== 'admin'} 
/>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply! That does make sense and I tried that and unfortunately, it did not work. If it helps, in Mongo, it is displayed as exactly... role: "admin"
I thought I would try.... !== "admin" as well which did not work

Comment: Did you state the role properly in the state? Check if there's a typo of "admin" or "Admin"?

Comment: Yes I checked for that and still not working for some reason - I might just try to do it a different way or it could be related to something else

Comment: Make sure your `Button` component passed disabled prop to native `button` DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

In which function you are setting the role to admin?

Comment: This is done on Mongo. I will attach what it looks like there if it helps

Comment: No am asking like where are you setting the state value to admin in class?

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are never setting role in the state, is below code ever logs "'User is an Admin'" seems No.

```
else if (this.state.role == 'admin') {
      console.log('User is an Admin');
      this.setState({
        disabled: false,
      })
    }
```

Set role in the state, it should help

Comment: Did that and still having the same issue. Perhaps I will try do it another way